Is there a way to calculate $I_{p,q}=\int_0^1 t^p(1-t)^q dt\text{ with } (p,q) \in \mathbb{N^2}$ without using the gamma function?
Given $I_{p,q}=\int_0^1 t^p(1-t)^q dt\quad \mbox{with}\quad (p,q) \in \mathbb{N^2}$, I tried by calculating $I_{0,0}$ and $I_{1,1}$ and so on until I got $I_{p,q}=\frac{p!\, q!}{\left(p + q\right)!}.$

Can you add more details to your attempt? What did you accomplish, where did you get stuck?

Also, are $p$ and $q$ non-negative integers?

Have you tried integral by parts?

I think you mean $\frac{p!q!}{(p+q+1)!}$. If you want to prove that for non-negative integers $p,,q$, I suggest finding a recursion relation using $t+(1-t)=1$.

how about using induction to prove your result?

That's a great idea. Induct on $p$. The base case is trivial. For the inductive step, use $t=1-(1-t)$.

If you don't then don't worry, but if you know of them, you could use the Laplace transform with convolution theorem.
$$I_{p,q}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}t^{p}(1-t)^{q}dt$$
Let $$I(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{x}t^{p}(x-t)^{q}dt$$
Notice $I(1)=I_{p,q}$, our goal. Consider the following functions:
$$f(t)=t^p,\;g(t)=t^q$$
$$I(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{x}f(t)g(x-t)dt=(f\ast g)(x)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\mathcal{L}(f\ast g))=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\mathcal{L}(f)\mathcal{L}(g))$$
$$\mathcal{L}(f)=\mathcal{L}(x^{p})=\frac{p!}{s^{p+1}}\\
\mathcal{L}(g)=\mathcal{L}(x^{q})=\frac{q!}{s^{q+1}}$$
$$I(x)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\frac{p!q!}{s^{p+q+1+1}})=\frac{p!q!}{(p+q+1)!}\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\frac{(p+q+1)!}{s^{p+q+1+1}})=\frac{p!q!}{(p+q+1)!}x^{p+q+1}$$
Finally, we just put in $x=1$ to get
$$I_{p,q}=I(1)=\frac{p!q!}{(p+q+1)!}$$

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable. Recall
$$ \textbf {P} \left[ X = x \left| \, n, p \right. \right] = \binom {n}{x} {p}^{x} {\left( 1 - p \right)}^{n - x}. $$
Suppose we have no prior information about the parametre $p$, so we assume that $p$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $\left[ 0, 1 \right]$. Then we expect
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \textbf {P} \left[ X = x \left| \, n, p \right. \right] \text {d} p = \frac {1}{n + 1}. $$
This should be intuitive: $x \in \{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$; there are a total of $n + 1$ possibilities, each equiprobable because of the lack of prior information about $p$. So
$$ \int_{0}^{1} {p}^{x} {\left( 1 - p \right)}^{n - x} \text {d} p = \frac {1}{n + 1} {\binom {n}{x}}^{- 1}. $$
This is as desired. We have managed to derive it without using the gamma function. $\blacksquare$

Alternatively, show that for all $\left( m, n \right) \in \mathbb {N}_{0} \times \mathbb {N}$,
$$
\begin{align}
{I}_{m, \, n}
& = \int_{0}^{1} {x}^{m} {\left( 1 - x \right)}^{n} \text {d} x \\
& = \frac {1}{m + 1} \int_{0}^{1} {\left( 1 - x \right)}^{n} \cdot \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} x} {x}^{m + 1} \cdot \text {d} x \\
& = \frac {1}{m + 1} {\bigg[ {x}^{m + 1} {\left( 1 - x \right)}^{n} \bigg]}_{x = 0}^{x = 1} - \frac {1}{m + 1} \int_{0}^{1} {x}^{m + 1} \cdot \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} x} {\left( 1 - x \right)}^{n} \cdot \text {d} x \\
& = - \frac {1}{m + 1} \int_{0}^{1} {x}^{m + 1} \cdot \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} x} {\left( 1 - x \right)}^{n} \cdot \text {d} x \\
& = \frac {n}{m + 1} \int_{0}^{1} {x}^{m + 1} {\left( 1 - x \right)}^{n - 1} \text {d} x \\
& = \frac {n}{m + 1} {I}_{m + 1, \, n - 1}.
\end{align}
$$
Rearrangement yields
$$ {I}_{m + 1, \, n - 1} = \frac {m + 1}{n} {I}_{m, \, n}. $$
By induction,
$$
\begin{align}
{I}_{k, \, n - k}
& = \frac {k}{n - k + 1} {I}_{k - 1, \, n - k + 1} \\
& = \frac {k}{n - k + 1} \cdot \frac {k - 1}{n - k + 2} {I}_{k - 2, \, n - k + 2} \\
& = \frac {k}{n - k + 1} \cdot \frac {k - 1}{n - k + 2} \cdot \frac {k - 2}{n - k + 3} {I}_{k - 3, \, n - k + 3} \\
& = \frac {k}{n - k + 1} \cdot \frac {k - 1}{n - k + 2} \cdot \frac {k - 2}{n - k + 3} \cdots \frac {k - j + 1}{n - k + j} {I}_{k - j, \, n - k + j} = \frac {k! \left( n - k \right)!}{n!} {I}_{0, \, n},
\end{align}
$$
where ${I}_{0, \, n} = 1 / \left( n + 1 \right)$. $\blacksquare$
